# Cheatsheet for the use of special characters syntax

Tags: syntax, named-characters

My favorite mass-use of special characters is if I have an expression that is linear in all variables (call the variable list $L$) and it must be identical zero. Then I generate my equation system with

```
D[%,#]&/@L
```

As you all know, % is the last expression, # marks a slot for a function, & indicates a function left of it and /@ maps the function over the following argument. There must be tons of this shortcuts, some of them I even don't know yet.

Thus my question: Is there a neat collection for the whole of MATHEMATICA syntax using special characters (defined by: not 0-9,A-Z and you find it on the keyboard)? (Especially: Is § really unused? :-) I already browsed [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframLanguageSyntaxCharacters.html) a bit, but as I said, it would be neat to have this on a single page.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/9490) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @JasonB.: Looks good! No wonder autocomplete didn't came up with that one. Immediately bookmarked, it even saved me bitching about the dreaded Suggestion Bar :-)